# The path Problem in menu product at checkout/cart page

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, url, cache

I have created a mega menu via one module in which i am facing a weird problem of url change. When i am on the homepage, category page or on product page the menu product URLs are working fine but on the cart page the menu product URLs are being changed to http://www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/product.html rather than http://www.mysite.com/product.html.

This issue get corrected when I flush the cache.

Comment: How do you generate the URLs in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using relative links.

Do you links look like

link.html
/link.html
../link.html
../../link.html

or something like that?

Try using just /link.html or put the store url like {{store url=""}}

You can use it like {{store url=""}}link.html or {{store url="link.html"}} either works for me though Im not sure which is technically correct.